# How to prove that $Sym(n, \mathbb{C}) \cap U(n) $ is a submanifold of $U(n)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, submanifold

I have found this exercise in Dusa McDuff "Introduction to symplectic topology" (2.3.6).
I don't see the way how to prove it. It hasn't coordinates where I can to check this, and also it's not the case of the theorem about closed subgroup of Lie group.

Comment: Just use the submersion theorem.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you. I thought about that, but I don't understand how to apply it in this case.

Comment: May use the function: $f: U(n) \to \mathbb C^{n^2}$, $f(A) = A-A^t$ or something like that I guess.

Comment: @ArcticChar The function $f$ has a trouble. The $Im f$ more than $Skew(n,\mathbb{R})$, but the $Im (df) = Skew(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Restrict the target space to a smaller subspace then.

Comment: @ArcticChar It won't help, because $Imf$ has matrices that are not lying in $Skew(n, \mathbb{R}) $, so I can't restrict it such that $df$ came surjective

Comment: How are you getting a matrix that is not skew-symmetric in the image of $f$? Isn't $(A-A^\top)^\top = A^\top - A = -(A-A^\top)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin It's not necessary that $f(A) $ is a real matrix,  because A isn't real. You can find such $A \in U(n) $ that $f(A)$ has nonzero imaginary part, but if $A \in \mathfrak{u} (n) $, i.e. $A$ skew-hermitian, then $A - A^T \in \mathbb{R} ^{n^2}$.

Comment: Note that if $A=A^\top$ and $AA^* = I$, then $A\bar A = I$ and $A\bar A$ is indeed a real matrix. So does that help?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, I think it won't help. Either it need to be choosen the unusual enough target space or I need to choose an other map.

Comment: I'm now convinced that this is not a standard exercise applying the submersion theorem. I do not own McDuff's book, so I cannot look in the book to see what relevant material is covered in that chapter/section.